# Understanding different definitions of bayes theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I am taking course on probability and reading about bayes theorem.

1. In [Sheldon Ross' book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013603313X), it given as 
   $$P(E) = P(E|F)P(F) + P(E|F^C)P(F^C)$$
   with note: Equation above states that the probability of the event E is a weighted average of the conditional probability of E given that F has occurred and the conditional probability of E given that F has not occurred – each conditional probability being given as much weight as the event on which it is conditioned had of occurring.
2. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#For_random_variables), it is given as $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
3. In [Kenneth Rosen's book](http://www.amazon.in/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0072899050) it is given as $$P(F|E)=\frac{P(F)P(E|F)}{P(E|F)P(F)\cup P(E|F^C)P(F^C)}$$

Though I understand proofs of all of those, I dont understand the connection between them or to say, **how they all communicate the same meaning**? Or am mistaking and they are talking about different stuff?

Comment: 1. is law of total probability

Comment: Could you please _proof-read_ your question? Does Rosen _really_ write the denominator as $P(E|F)P(F)\cup P(E|F^C)P(F^C)$? and if so, how does he define the _union_ of two probabilities?

Comment: That should be a $+$ rather than a $\cup$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 1. is known as the law of total probability

Equation 2. is Bayes' theorem.

Equation 3. is Bayes' theorem with the law of total probability applied on A and B on the $P(B)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia's version is correct, $P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.

However often you know $P(B|A)$, and you have to calculate $P(B)$. This is basically (1) in your expressions above, using that you can write

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^C)P(A^C)}$ which gives (3) - almost always your problems will require this form to solve real life problems.

So (2) and (3) are Bayes Theorem, (1) is not. And *almost* everytime you will end up using (3).

---

Remembering a typical example,

**Example:** One box has 3 white, 5 red. Another has 4 white, 4 red. I pulled out a box randomly, and a ball randomly from it. The ball is red. What's the probability it came from first box?

$A=$first box

$B=$red

Using (3) we get

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^C)P(A^C)}=\frac{5/8\times1/2}{5/8\times1/2+4/8\times1/2}=5/9$